# Error wallet.connect() is not a function, but it just worked a couple minutes ago

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethers.js

``

I am trying to complete the FCC solidty course. I'm at the 7:45 mark. Everything was going smoothly and I successfully(i think) encrypted the RPC url, private key, and password. I am now trying to connect my wallet variable to the provider variable using the connect function.

It worked perfectly before my encryption, but why would it be saying "wallet.connect is not a function" if the problem has to do with the values being trash. This is why I'm not sure what the problem is. Here is the code and error message.

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
require("dotenv").config();

async function main() {
  // http://127.0.0.1:7545
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.RPC_URL);
  // console.log(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);
  // const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider);
  const encryptedJson = fs.readFileSync("./.encryptedKey.json", "utf8");
  let wallet = new ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJson(
    encryptedJson,
    process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD
  );
  wallet = await wallet.connect(provider);
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf8"
  );
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(); //Stop here! wait for contract to deploy
  await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1);
  //Get number
  const currentFavoriteNumber = await contract.retrieve();
  console.log(`Current Favorite Number: ${currentFavoriteNumber.toString()}`);
  const transactionResponse = await contract.store("7");
  const transactionReciept = await transactionResponse.wait(1);
  const updatedFavoriteNumber = await contract.retrieve();
  console.log(`Updated favorite number is: ${updatedFavoriteNumber}`);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

```
TypeError: wallet.connect is not a function
    at main (/home/dylan/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/deploy.js:15:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dylan/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/deploy.js:34:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly mistake actually. fromEncryptedJson should be fromEncryptedJsonSync.

Comment: Voted to close as a typo instead.

Comment: Same happened to me, you are not alone :)